# Change some data in input field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i need with jQuery to change data in input field when user click on some link

`<input value="height-size-width">`

so when user click on some

```
<a href = "#" id="width">
```

link need to change only widht in input field....

if user click

```
<a href = "#" id="height">
```

link script need to change only height in input field...

Like youtube embed option
Any help?

Comment: I really can't tell what this means.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Technical questions don't need the "Community Wiki" checkbox, that is for poll type questions only. Can you clarify your question somewhat? It's hard to understand right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input id="embed-code" size="60" />
<h3>Select size:</h3>
<ul id="embed-size-options">
    <li><a href="#" data-width="640" data-height="480" class="selected">640x480</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-width="800" data-height="600">800x600</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-width="1024" data-height="768">1024x768</a></li>
</ul>

<h3>Select color:</h3>
<ul id="embed-color-options">
    <li><a href="#" data-color="#ff0000" class="selected">red</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-color="#00ff00">green</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-color="#0000ff">blue</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="sprintf-0.6.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var $embed_code = $('#embed-code'),
            $embed_size_options = $('#embed-size-options'),
            $embed_color_options = $('#embed-color-options'),
            $selected_size = $embed_size_options.find('a.selected').eq(0),
            $selected_color = $embed_color_options.find('a.selected').eq(0),
            code_tpl = 'current width %s and height %s and color %s';
        if (!$selected_size) {
            $selected_size = $embed_size_options.find('a').eq(0).addClass('selected');
        }
        if (!$selected_color) {
            $selected_color = $embed_color_options.find('a').eq(0).addClass('selected');
        }
        generate_embed_code();

        $embed_size_options.find('a').click(function() {
            $selected_size.removeClass('selected');
            $selected_size = $(this).addClass('selected');
            generate_embed_code();
            return false;
        });
        $embed_color_options.find('a').click(function() {
            $selected_color.removeClass('selected');
            $selected_color = $(this).addClass('selected');
            generate_embed_code();
            return false;
        });
        function generate_embed_code() {
            $embed_code.val(sprintf(code_tpl, $selected_size.attr('data-width'), $selected_size.attr('data-height'), $selected_color.attr('data-color')));
        }
    });
</script>
```

Is this what you want?

(I used [this JavaScript sprintf() implementation](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/sprintf-for-javascript) to generate the embed code)

Answer (score 0):

Youtube does not just change the dimensions, but rewrites the whole string...

So, you need to hold each property in its own variable and just recreate the whole value..

Javascript

```
var height = 500; // default value
var width = 500; // default value
var size = 500; // default value

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#dimensions').val(height + '-' + size + '-' + width);

   // assuming that you put a different id to each a href (id : width or height or size)
   // do the following for each button
   $('#width').click(function(){
     width = 700;
     $('#dimensions').val(height + '-' + size + '-' + width);
     return false;
   });
});
```

HTML

```
<input value="height-size-width" id="dimension">
<a href="#" id="width">change width</a>
```

Comment: @John, just add an extra attribute on your link.. and use it (*like oblio showed :)*)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` and `join` methods to get the values and put them together again. Example:

```
<input type="text" id="data" value="178-4-56" />

<a href="javascript:var values=$('#data').val().split('-');values[0]=parseInt(values[0])+1;$('#data').val(values.join('-'));">increase height</a>
<a href="javascript:var values=$('#data').val().split('-');values[1]=parseInt(values[1])+1;$('#data').val(values.join('-'));">increase size</a>
<a href="javascript:var values=$('#data').val().split('-');values[2]=parseInt(values[2])+1;$('#data').val(values.join('-'));">increase width</a>
```